# Have rotated column headers

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, tableheader

I am trying to add a class to each table header so that they can be rotated on a angle at the top of the table. The table headers are populated from an array of items. Currently the code i have has roated the full table head not the individual table headers

```
function renderMatrix(){
    var actions = getActions();
    for(var i=0;i<actions.length;i++){
        $("#actionTable>thead>tr").append("<th>"+ actions[i] +"</th>");
        $("#actionTable>thead>tr").addClass("rotateHeader")
        
    }
```

---

```
.rotateHeader
{transform: 
    translate(25px, 51px)

    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
```

What would be the best way to go about making it so the only things rotated is the text in the column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#actionTable").find("th").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(315deg)')
```

Comment: Would be great if you also provide the snippet for it

Comment: That has worked for what I asked but I think I have asked the wrong question. That has rotated the text so it fits in the box diagonally but I would also like the boxes to be diaganol so they fit together and manage space better. How would I be able to rotate the text as well as the box the text is in

Comment: I think, maybe this is what you looking for: https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/